# Grouping the results of multiple rows in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The query below gives me two results where everything is same except the last column v2_roles.id. Is there a way to group them in one column (may be a comma seprated list) and get just one result back

```
SELECT v2_admin.adminid, 
       v2_admin.adminname, 
       v2_admin.login, 
       v2_admin.email, 
       v2_roles.id 
FROM   v2_admin 
       INNER JOIN v2_admin_roles 
               ON v2_admin.adminid = v2_admin_roles.adminid 
       INNER JOIN v2_roles 
               ON v2_admin_roles.roleid = v2_roles.id 
WHERE  v2_admin.adminid = 2
```

Comment: Soory missed that MSSQL 2008

Comment: Provide sample data and what you want for a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should also work,

```
;WITH mytable AS (
   SELECT v2_admin.adminid, 
       v2_admin.adminname, 
       v2_admin.login, 
       v2_admin.email, 
       v2_roles.id 
   FROM   v2_admin 
       INNER JOIN v2_admin_roles 
               ON v2_admin.adminid = v2_admin_roles.adminid 
       INNER JOIN v2_roles 
               ON v2_admin_roles.roleid = v2_roles.id 
   WHERE  v2_admin.adminid = 2 
)

SELECT t1.adminid,t1.adminname, t1.login, t1.email,
       roleIds =REPLACE( (SELECT convert(varchar,id) AS [data()]
                FROM mytable t2
                WHERE t2.adminid = t1.adminid
                --ORDER BY t2.adminid
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), ' ', ' , ')
FROM mytable t1
GROUP BY t1.adminid,t1.adminname, t1.login, t1.email ;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works as expected

Answer (score 1):

This is a little trick using `FOR XML` to convert the field to a list and `STUFF` to remove the beginning comma -- this should be close (untested):

```
SELECT v2_admin.adminid, 
       v2_admin.adminname, 
       v2_admin.login, 
       v2_admin.email, 
       STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ',' +  CAST(v2_roles.id as varchar) AS [text()]
                FROM v2_roles
                WHERE v2_admin_roles.roleid = v2_roles.id 
            ORDER BY v2_roles.id
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '') AS Roles
FROM   v2_admin 
       INNER JOIN v2_admin_roles 
               ON v2_admin.adminid = v2_admin_roles.adminid 
WHERE  v2_admin.adminid = 2 
GROUP BY v2_admin.adminid, 
       v2_admin.adminname, 
       v2_admin.login, 
       v2_admin.email
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it give error  - Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ','
to data type int.

Comment: Cast your Roles.Id -- one sec and I'll edit...

Comment: @nasaa -- see edits -- you just needed to cast your int to a varchar -- best of luck!

Comment: Sorry but it still gives me two rows. Answer from KAF above has the solution to my problem. Thanks

Comment: @nasaa -- no worries -- looks like I left off GROUP BY -- main key (to both of our answers), use FOR XML :) -- Glad we could help nonetheless...